# How can I view anonymous opinions on sayat.me?

Tags: sayat.me

How can I view anonymous opinions on sayat.me?

[image: sayat.met]

I have tried looking around the site but was not able to find out how. I have also ran a few google searches to no avail

Answer (score 1):

These can be viewed by the user who got these feedbacks. They are visible at the logged-in frontpage of that user.